# div inside another div with loop using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, for-loop

I'm trying to create 5 divs inside another 5 divs using loop in javascript. I have made the main divs but all small divs are created only in one main div and only three small divs are created. How to make one small div for one main div? The same thing must repeat 5 times.

```js
for(let n=0; n<5; n++){
  var elm = document.createElement('div');
  elm.id="comments";
  document.getElementById('elm').appendChild(elm);

  var sec = document.createElement('div');
  sec.id = "sec";
  document.getElementById('comments').appendChild(sec);
}
```

```css
#elm{
  width: 90vw;
  height: 90vh;
  background: blue;
 }
#comments{
  background: brown;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  border: 2px solid yellow;
 }
#sec{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: chartreuse;
  z-index: 1000;
  border: 2px solid darkgreen;
 }
```

```html
<div id="elm"></div>
```

Comment: Ids have to be **unqiue**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attribute [**`id`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) must be unique in a document, use [**`class`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class) instead. Also, you should append the *sec* element inside the currently created *comments* element in each iteration:

```js
for(let n=0; n<5; n++){
  var elm = document.createElement('div');
  elm.setAttribute('class',"comments");
  document.getElementById('elm').appendChild(elm);

  var sec = document.createElement('div');
  sec.setAttribute('class', "sec");
  elm.appendChild(sec); // append the sec element inside the current comments element
}
```

```css
#elm{
  width: 90vw;
  height: 90vh;
  background: blue;
}
.comments{
  background: brown;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  border: 2px solid yellow;
}
.sec{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: chartreuse;
  z-index: 1000;
  border: 2px solid darkgreen;
}
```

```html
<div id="elm"></div>
```